# Menu not aligning properly when using jquery for additional functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a mega menu similar to one as show in image below
[image]

So far i have been able to make it work to some extent example on [jsFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4RFtc/).

So far i have some design issue and one functionality issue.

When i try to hide the default text for each dropdown menu `//$(this).find(".nav-info").hide();` then  Menu 4 & 5 does not  show up on right side.

I am actually trying to create a menu similar to one as on this [website](http://www.hlgroup.com/en/section/capabilities).
One this website they also show a default text for parent menu which i dont need actually.

I modified script to show the first li of submenu it works find for Parent menu ONE, TWO but creates alignment problem for MENU FOUR and FIVE.

I would appreciate if some can help me fix this issue...

CODE

```
<div class="container_16">
    <div class="nav-main grid_16">
        <div class="wrap-nav-media">
            <ul id="nav-top-media">
                <!-- ONE -->
                <li class="nav-item-1"><a href="../company-overview">Parent Menu One</a>

                    <div style="display: none;" class="inner-nav-media">
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="../directors" rel="sub-1-relative-1">sub-1-relative-1</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="../management-team" rel="sub-1-relative-2">sub-1-relative-2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="last"><a class="current" href="../tems.html" rel="sub-1-relative-3">sub-1-relative-3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="display: block;" class="menu-page first" id="mega-sub-1-relative-1">    <a href="../board-of-directors" title="Board of Directors" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-1-relative-1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: block;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-1-relative-2">  <a href="../management-team" title="Management Team" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow; float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-1-relative-2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-1-relative-3">   <a href="../vision.html" title="Vision" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-1-relative-3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- TWO -->
                <li class="nav-item-2"> <a href="../capabilities">Parent Menu TWO</a>

                    <div style="display: none;" class="inner-nav-media">
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="../infrastructure" rel="sub-2-relative-1">sub-2-relative-1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="../capabilities/building" rel="sub-2-relative-2">sub-2-relative-2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="last"><a class="current" href="../capabilities/rail" rel="sub-2-relative-3">sub-2-relative-3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page first" id="mega-sub-2-relative-1"> <a href="../infrastructure" title="Infrastructure" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-2-relative-1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-2-relative-2">   <a href="../building" title="Building" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                    <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-2-relative-2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-2-relative-3">   <a href="../rail" title="Rail" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-2-relative-3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item-3"><a href="../projects">THREE</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item-4"> <a href="../-businesses">FOUR</a>

                    <div style="display: none;" class="inner-nav-media">
                        <div style="display: block; float:right;" class="menu-page nav-info">   <a class="thumb" rel="nofollow" title=" Businesses" href="../businesses">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>TEXT will be here...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="">   <a class="current" href="2.html" rel="sub-4-relative-1">sub-4-relative-1</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="">   <a class="current" href="1.html" rel="sub-4-relative-2">sub-4-relative-2</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page first" id="mega-sub-4-relative-1"> <a href="../group.html" title="" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <img src="HLG-Mega-Menu_files/20110602_1-ARG.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>TEXT will be here...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-4-relative-2">   <a href="../advance-water-and-environmentawe.html" title="Advance Water and Environment (AWE)" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <img src="HLG-Mega-Menu_files/20121024_AWG-220x165.jpg" alt="Advance Water and Environment (AWE)">
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>TEXT will be here...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="last nav-item-5"><a href="../sustainability">FIVE</a>

                    <div style="display: none;" class="inner-nav-media">
                        <div style="display: block;" class="menu-page nav-info">    <a class="thumb" rel="nofollow" title="" href="">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>This is Default text when i try to hide this then this menu moves to left</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="" rel="sub-5-relative-1">sub-5-relative-1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="" rel="sub-5-relative-2">sub-5-relative-2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="" rel="sub-5-relative-3">sub-5-relative-3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="last"><a class="current" href="" rel="sub-5-relative-4">sub-5-relative-4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page first" id="mega-sub-5-relative-1"> <a href="../safety.html" title="" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-5-relative-3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-5-relative-2">   <a href="../environment.html" title="Environment" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-5-relative-2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-5-relative-3">   <a href="../community.html" title="Community" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-5-relative-3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-5-relative-4">   <a href="../quality.html" title="Quality" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-5-relative-4</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

WHEN i try to hide html code block show below it break the alignment of MENU FOUR & FIVE using `$(this).find(".nav-info").hide();`

```
<div style="display: block;" class="menu-page nav-info">    <a class="thumb" rel="nofollow" title="" href="">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

    <div>
        <p>This is Default text when i try to hide this then this menu moves to left</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `$(this).find(".nav-info").find("p").hide();` instead.

Comment: this will hide p for other menus also.. and it did..

Comment: I updated the code.. check again.

Comment: @Mr_Green, Check update, my problem is when i try to hide code block or div with class `nav-info` it then breaks the design for menu FOUR and FIVE. you can check it on fiddle which is mention on question itself. You code hides the p but div remains.

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue. [note] you are changing styles using external styles, inline styles and jquery. This is real mess. Try using just external styles and if necessary, jquery. I am sure most of the part of menu can be done using just css.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: Mr_Green is right - tidy up your code and do not use any inline styles! The best way to use jQuery in such cases is to simply add or remove css classes for the respective elements. And after a first quick look at your JS code I am quite sure that you also may simplify it. But first of all please clean up your code.

Comment: @Netsurfer, I have cleaned up code as much as i can, as i am  not a guru removing some parts of code create problem. I have managed to make it work to some extend and may make it work for my. But i would rather request our experts for a more professional solution as their is not much related to this article i mean similar kind of menus. Updated fiddle ..http://jsfiddle.net/4RFtc/3/

Comment: @Netsurfer, I worked on another approach which looks clean but is not working as desired fiddle css example http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/6/

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: Are you looking for something like [**this**](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/819_megamenu/demo/index.html)?

Comment: @Netsurfer, I already looked at this i basically looking for somthing on same line but with `ul` list as submenu's and next to sub menu it should show related information. Mix of two. i want something on these line jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/6

Comment: @netsurfer, this was one of the first mega menus i looked at.

Comment: I see so many JS and I dont think those are necessary. This menu can be written with plain CSS and very few lines of JS. Would it be helpful if I provide you a clean solution?

Comment: @shekhardesigner, I would prefer pure css solution, I would appreciate if you can help me with this. I also tried some like pure css but i am not able to get it right example http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/5/

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker You have my answer, please check if that helps you!

Comment: @shekhardesigner, I will check... Appreciate your answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the site you were referring for the example And you can achieve the same with plain CSS and few lines of jQuery. Here is my way:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Menu One</a>
            <div  class="dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu one</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/animals/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu one - sub menu one</strong>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu two</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu one - sub menu two</strong>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu three</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/business/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu one - sub menu three</strong>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu four</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/people/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu one - sub menu four</strong>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#">Menu Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Three</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sample link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sample link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sample link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sample link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Long Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Four &amp; Long</a>
            <div  class="dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu inner</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/animals/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu Four &amp; Long - sub menu inner </strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam turpis magna, condimentum sit amet interdum quis, gravida accumsan risus. Donec vulputate dolor in turpis ornare, sed dictum ligula pretium. Nullam sed dolor mollis magna auctor porttitor.  Duis sem sem, pretium non lorem vitae, lacinia eleifend ligula. Aliquam ipsum erat, gravida eget hendrerit in, fermentum vel odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt. </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu two</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/animals/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu one - sub menu one</strong>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu three</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/animals/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu one - sub menu one</strong>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu four</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu having long texxt</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/animals/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu one - sub menu one</strong>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu three consectqtero</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                            <img class="media" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/160/animals/" alt="image" />
                            <p class="media-caption"><strong>Menu one - sub menu one</strong>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque porta varius tortor, ac luctus lorem condimentum vel. Mauris venenatis justo id fringilla tincidunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu four</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font:normal 14px Arial, Sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav {
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.nav li {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}

.nav > li {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#ccc;
    background:#444;
    min-width:160px;
}

.nav > li > a {
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

.dropdown {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    color:#444;
    min-height:160px;
    background:#ccc;
}

.dropdown.has-panel {
    width:600px;
}

.dropdown > ul {
    width:180px;
    background:#ccc;
}

.dropdown > ul > li {
    position:static;
}

.dropdown > ul > li > a {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.dropdown-last {
    left:auto;
    right:0;
}

.dropdown-last > ul {
    float:right;
}

.dropdown li > a {
    color:#555;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
    display:block;
}

.dd-panel {
    position:absolute;
    background:#ccc;
    left:180px;
    top:0;
    width:380px;
    padding:20px;
    display:none;
    bottom:0;
}

.dropdown li:first-child .dd-panel,
.dropdown li:hover .dd-panel {
    display:block;
}

.dropdown-last .dd-panel{
    left:auto;
    right:180px;
}

.dd-panel > .media {
    float:left;
    margin:3px 20px 10px 0;
    max-height:130px;
}

.media-caption {
    margin:0;
}

.dropdown li a:hover {
    color:#000;
    background:#bfbfbf;
}

.nav li:hover {
    background:#ccc;
}

.nav li:hover > a  {
    color:#444;
}
.nav li:hover .dropdown {
    display:block;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").on("mouseenter", " > li", function(){

        /*if dropdown is likely to go out of parent nav then right align it :) */
        if (($(this).offset().left) + 600 > $('.nav').width()) {
            $(this).find(".dropdown").addClass("dropdown-last");
        }
    });

    /* if dropdnw*/
    $(".dropdown").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.find(".dd-panel").length > 0){
            $this.addClass('has-panel');
        }
    });
});
```

See it working on JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/wPWDm/

Comment: For future reference, I saved this on my Git: https://github.com/shekhardesigner/MegaDropdown

Comment: Pure magic... This is wonderful..  I was looking for pure css solution for last one week but could not find much of help, I am sure your solution will help others also I must thanks also Sombre he also provide pure css solution which could be of great help to other. I wish i can mark both as correct answers or reward both user. Thanks you very much for the magic script.

Comment: I was not sure how to reward bounty.. Just did that by clicking on the +150 i hope you got your my bounty for correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@KnowledgeSeeker , your code is perfect but no need to show and hide you can just keep one global variable for each like:

```
    var html_4=""; 
    and 
    var html_5="";
```

for both menu and then keep your inner html code in that variables separately. After that you just do with this code : (For tab four)

```
    $(this).find(".nav-info").html("");
    $(this).find(".nav-info").html(html_4);
```

same for five also, just replace variable name for other tab you need to html null for these tabs and keep this class always because if you remove class your css issue will be appear.

Comment: brother i haven't jsfiddle account but i used this method in my previous project. once try with this hope it will helps you because i edited in your code and tried.

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and implemented this in pure css. It relies on specifically-defined widths and heights as well as absolute positioning for the details. Thus the popup boxes won't automatically resize to fit its content.

The details require a background because, to simulate the first item already being shown, I just always show it. The other items, when hovered, just hover on top of the first item. If no background exists, you will be able to see the first item's details behind it.

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-mega">
    <li class="dd-mega-item">
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="dd-mega-sub">
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 1</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 2</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 3</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 3</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-mega-item">
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="dd-mega-sub">
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 1</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 2</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 3</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 3</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-mega-item">
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="dd-mega-sub">
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 1</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 2</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 3</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 3</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-mega-item is-aligned-right">
        <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
        <ul class="dd-mega-sub">
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 1</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 2</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 3</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 3</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-mega-item is-aligned-right">
        <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
        <ul class="dd-mega-sub">
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 1</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 2</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-mega-sub-item">
                <a href="#">Submenu 3</a>
                <div class="dd-mega-sub-item-details">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
                    <p>Details for Submenu 3</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-mega, .dropdown-mega ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-mega li {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .dd-mega-item {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        }

        .dd-mega-item > a {
            background-color: #08f;
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            padding: 0 40px;
            text-decoration: none;
            vertical-align: middle;
            }

        .dd-mega-item:hover > a {
            background-color: #06d;
            color: #f80;
            text-decoration: underline;
            }

        .dd-mega-item:hover > .dd-mega-sub > .dd-mega-sub-item:first-child > .dd-mega-sub-item-details {
            display: block;
            z-index: 9;
            }

        .dd-mega-sub {
            background-color: #0af;
            display: none;
            left: 0;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            width: 500px;
            z-index: 10;
            }

            .dd-mega-sub-item {
                clear: left;
                float: left;
                width: 100px;
                }

                .dd-mega-sub-item > a {
                    background-color: #0cf;
                    color: #000;
                    display: block;
                    height: 30px;
                    line-height: 30px;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    }

                .dd-mega-sub-item:hover > a {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                    }

                .dd-mega-sub-item-details {
                    background-color: #0ff;
                    display: none;
                    height: 200px;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 400px;
                    z-index: 10;
                    }

                    .dd-mega-sub-item-details > img {
                        float: right;
                        }

                .dd-mega-sub-item:hover > .dd-mega-sub-item-details {
                    display: block;
                    }

        .dd-mega-item:hover > .dd-mega-sub {
            display: block;
            }

        .dd-mega-item.is-aligned-right > .dd-mega-sub {
            left: auto;
            right: 0;
            }

            .dd-mega-item.is-aligned-right > .dd-mega-sub >  .dd-mega-sub-item {
                clear: right;
                float: right;
                }

            .dd-mega-item.is-aligned-right > .dd-mega-sub >  .dd-mega-sub-item > .dd-mega-sub-item-details {
                left: 0;
                right: auto;
                }
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ugd/1/)

Comment: Can you please tell me which IE browsers it will support

Comment: Let me test it in IE7 real quick. It won't work in IE6 since it is using a combined class name `.dd-mega-item.is-aligned-right` as well as the child `>` selector. However, those can be changed to work in IE6. Of course, I'm sure there are other things that need to be fixed to go back that far.

Comment: I dont need IE 6 support but it should work on IE 7 atleast, & for backgroud image which you have mentioned i think i can using jquery to always select the first item as done in this example.. http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/6/ it has a bug which can me fixed later. What do u say..

Comment: You can definitely use jQuery to accomplish the same thing; however, it's not so necessary. The background doesn't need to be an image. It can be the same color as the rest of the box, as long as it has a color. It works in IE7; however, I had to add two rules to the stylesheet. I have updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ugd/1/ Unfortunately, I do not have IE8 on hand to test at the moment; so you may want to test all the IE versions at some point if you choose to use this.

Answer (score 2):

You could have tried http://greengeckodesign.com/menumatic/ or Nettus+ has nice article about it:
http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/819_megamenu/demo/index.html