# Mobile collapse bootstrap not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly competent with HTML and am working with Bootstrap for the first time, but I can't seem to get the mobile collapsible menu working on Chrome on the desktop (and presumably some other browsers).

Safari on iOS 7 with default mobile responsiveness shows the menu fine when clicked, but nothing happens when you click it in Chrome on the PC when the browser is resized to a mobile-like width.

Sorry if it has been said before - just went through the code and couldn't really understand why it wasn't working! :(

First time on SO and can't figure out how to put my HTML in here, so [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/122550/diylab/index.html) it is.

Thanks peeps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have linked jQuery from Google CDN and hosting your website from Dropbox. Dropbox does not allow external linking of script and font files.

So you are getting an error on your page:

[image]

Host the jQuery file on your website and link (internal linking). Like for example put jQuery in JS folder and link:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Problem will be gone. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952092/menu-not-aligning-properly-when-using-jquery-for-additional-functionality as you did mention you can help me in this